# Edmx not returning auto incremented value

Tags: c#, oracle11g, entity-framework-5

I am using Oracle 11g  database. Many tables created in database and indexer applied on Primary key. After that i used Entity Framework 5.0 to connect with database. 
The issue is that , when i am saving any record in table, it doesn't send Primary key which is  auto incremented value.

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostCategory(TBLCATEGORY tblcategory)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.TBLCATEGORies.Add(tblcategory);
            db.SaveChanges();
            int32 ID=tblcategory.ID;
            return ID;
        }
    }
```

it returns ID =0;
And one more thing, while creating any column Integer in oracle, it is showing decimal in Entity Framework.

Comment: You haven't mixed up GET and POST have you? If you're posting then you might be missing the HttpPost attribute?

Comment: Ron, Thanks for answer. 
I am using webApi in mvc, so if we are posting any method , we need to just prefix Post before method name. NO need to define GET and Post method separately . And i don't think so , it affects edmx updation.because it saves data in database. And it should returns primary key.

Comment: Just to make sure that that method is indeed the method that is invoked. 
Is it specific to this table? Is it working for other tables?

Comment: i am using this method , to create a category and for this table only.And it is big problem for me. Because , due to this problem, i am querying twice to get "ID", which is performance issue.While same thing working fine with SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have defined a sequence and a trigger in the Oracle database that does the auto increment of the ID column, so only the object in the EF model is not updated, but the actual entry in the database has the correct incremented ID value, right?

Then the problem is that the edmx model does not know that the column is actually an ID column where the value is generated in the database. You have to manually edit the edmx model. The respective column entry in the SSDL section must have the StoreGeneratedPattern property set to "Identity". This tells the model to check again the database after inserting to look up the generated ID value. However, everytime you update the model from the database, your manual changes are lost.

I have written a short blog post about it: http://blog.aitgmbh.de/2014/06/02/patch-for-entity-framework-models-based-on-oracle-databases/

And I have created a NuGet package that does everything for you whenever you build the project: http://bit.ly/1hbxIsO

This way, even after updating your edmx model, the Identity property is added again to the specified ID columns.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the following articles:

problem description:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/505178/storegeneratedpattern-property-in-ado-net-entity-model-designer-sets-cdsl-annotation-but-not-ssdl-attribute

solution to the problem:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a63745c0-a781-48fa-a7d2-573ee80b5d7e